# Found conflicting getters for name: isImportantForAccessibility

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app which will Upload the Value and Image of the Product on click of each Grid View item.

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.intuition.ivposcloud;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import static android.R.attr.name;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Write a message to the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
    GridView grid;
    String[] web = {
            "Pizza",
            "Cheese",
            "Cake",
            "Icecream",
            "Chocolate shake",
            "coffee",
            "Cake2",
            "Yummy",
            "Chicken",
            "Tikka",
            "pizza2",
            "pizza3",
            "Butter",
            "Chocolate Cake",
            "Nothing"

    };

    String[] web1 = {
            "120",
            "111",
            "123",
            "12",
            "121",
            "155",
            "575",
            "72",
            "145",
            "251",
            "412",
            "124",
            "124",
            "412",
            "142"

    };


    int[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image7,
            R.drawable.image8,
            R.drawable.image9,
            R.drawable.image10,
            R.drawable.image11,
            R.drawable.image12,
            R.drawable.image13,
            R.drawable.image14,
            R.drawable.image15

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked position at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position] + "price is " + web1[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//                final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
//                String ImageView = image.getImageMatrix().toString().trim();
                String TextView = text.getText().toString().trim();
                Item item = new Item();

//                myRef.child("Image").setValue(item);
                myRef.child("Text").setValue(text);

                //Value event listener for realtime data update
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            //Getting the data from snapshot
                            Item item = postSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);

                            //Adding it to a string
                            String string = "Item name: " + item.getText() + "\n Item Image: " + item.getImage() + "\n\n";

                            //Displaying it on textview
//                            textViewPersons.setText(string);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot Read Data" + DatabaseError.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
                    }

                });
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Here is - Item.java Class

```
    package com.example.intuition.ivposcloud;

import static android.R.attr.name;

/**
 * Created by intuition on 14-12-2016.
 */

public class Item {
    //name and address string
    private String image;
    private String text;

    public Item() {
      /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/
    }
    //Getters and setters
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Here is the LogCat Fatal error I got after I run the app.

LogCat:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.intuition.ivposcloud, PID: 16884
                                               com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isImportantForAccessibility
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaw(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.example.intuition.ivposcloud.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:112)
                                                   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1152)
                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide the [minimum code + JSON (as text, no screenshot) that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example: I doubt all the images are needed to reproduce the problem, but they're distracting from the actual cause. In addition none of your code defines a `isImportantForAccessibility` field nor a similar property in JSON. Without an MCVE, we'll just be taking educated guesses.

Comment: Your post shows `Item` declared in its own file.  The failure could occur if `Item` was declared inside a class that extended from `View`.  Was `Item` previously declared as an nested class?  Have you done a Clean of your project?

Comment: @qbix yes, I tried clean project but issue still there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I checked, I didnt used isImportantForAccessibility anywhere.

Comment: @qbix Can you please upload any code working fine to upload value from gridview to Firebase. That would be really helpful.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you please upload any code working fine to upload value from gridview to Firebase. That would be really helpful.

Comment: I agree with frank's answer. In firebase database we cannot store values other than json type. So we need to change it to string and then we can store it in firebase database.

Answer (score 8):

This will not work:

```
final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
myRef.child("Text").setValue(text);
```

The Firebase Database can only store JSON types, so you cannot pass a `TextView` to it.

You're likely looking to store the value from the text view in the database, which you'd do with:

```
final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
myRef.child("Text").setValue(text.getText().toString());
```

Comment: how to set map in firestore?